# Ejabberd configure: error: libyaml library was not found

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, libyaml

I am trying to install Ejabberd by source code, But When I run make command I have found
following Error.

```
checking for yaml_parser_initialize in -lyaml... no
checking yaml.h usability... no
checking yaml.h presence... no
checking for yaml.h... no
configure: error: libyaml library was not found
ERROR: Command ['get-deps'] failed!
make: *** [deps/.got] Error 1
```

I have reinstall libyaml 0.2 and other version using make and brew as well but still not solve the error.
If you know another solution than guide me.

Comment: I guess that you need to install the development version of all required libraries

Comment: Do you know at which path ejabberd search libyaml? ro How to change Path so that ejabberd search libyaml on given PATH.

Answer (score 15):

I just install libyaml-dev:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libyaml-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue, make and install [libyaml](http://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml) then you will be able to compile ejabberd

```
cd tmp/
sudo wget http://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/yaml-0.1.6.tar.gz
sudo tar xzvf yaml-0.1.6.tar.gz 
cd yaml-0.1.6/
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Is sudo necessary when running all those commands?

Answer (score 2):

You can install libyaml-devel in centos

```
sudo yum install libyaml-devel
```